# Listen to OX X NSNotificationCenter notifications in node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, nsnotifications

I'd love to be able to listen in on some notifications getting sent through OS X' `NSNotificationCenter`, but I'm not all that familiar with Swift, nor have the desire to change all of my code to be based on Swift. Is there *any* way I can tap into the notifications and listen to notifications from node.js directly?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm currently trying to achieve the same thing.